# How does Xamarin.Essentials deal with the iOS “Documents” folder?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, filesystems, xamarin.essentials

I followed the “[build mobile apps with Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/build-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms/)” course. On the “[store local data with SQLite in a Xamarin.Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/store-local-data-with-sqlite/)” section, they say iOS provides two folders to deal with the files saved on a device:

- the **Documents** folder, for user-generated data only.
- the **Library** folder, for for app-generated data.

Then, this subsection is presented:

[image]

What I don’t understand is: is this the correct way to deal with the iOS **Documents** folder? I ask this because they explicitly say `libFolder` contains the appropriate **Library** location. What about the **Documents** folder required by Apple’s guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are detailed information about different purposes of folders in iOS, in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories):

**Documents:/**

> Use this directory to store user documents and application data files.
>
> The contents of this directory can be made available to the user
> through iTunes file sharing (although this is disabled by default).
> Add a UIFileSharingEnabled Boolean key to the Info.plist file to allow
> users to access these files.
>
> Even if an application doesn’t immediately enable file sharing, you
> should avoid placing files that should be hidden from your users in
> this directory (such as database files, unless you intend to share
> them). As long as sensitive files remain hidden, these files will not
> be exposed (and potentially moved, modified, or deleted by iTunes) if
> file sharing is enabled in a future version.
>
> You can use the Environment.GetFolderPath
> (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) method to get the path to the
> Documents directory for your application.
>
> The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

**Library/:**

> The Library directory is a good place to store files that are not
> created directly by the user, such as databases or other
> application-generated files. The contents of this directory are never
> exposed to the user via iTunes.
>
> You can create your own subdirectories in Library; however, there are
> already some system-created directories here that you should be aware
> of, including Preferences and Caches.
>
> The contents of this directory (except for the Caches subdirectory)
> are backed up by iTunes. Custom directories that you create in Library
> will be backed up.

Please read the document and feel free to ask if you have other problems.

**Update**

to access update answer:

iOS:

```
string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string libFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library");
```

Android:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still don’t find an answer to my question. As I read, the **Documents** folder is where I place user-generated files, but I still can’t figure out how Xamarin.Essentials deals with it.

Comment: The section you read is about Sqlite and Xamarin recommend you to store Sqlite in the library folder. Xamarin.Essentials give a quick way for you the access the library folder. Xamarin.Essentials does not give you a quick way to access the document folder. If you want to access the the  document folder, see my updated answer.